# some help for a newb

Tags: css, css-transitions

I watched a video on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wZwnBkUDK9Q) for a cool shopping page using css transitions in dreamweaver.
I am trying to re-create the page but I am having some trouble in trying to lay it out to that the text is at the bottom of the picture, but I cannot figure it out. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any code that you have attempted in laying out? Best to start with a minimal example and work from there. Please also use a more descriptive question, that is specific to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

After many hours of searching their (rediculously long) css pages, I have managed to pull out the relevant code piece by piece.
If anyone is interested, I have posted it on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GXezr/1/).

I sorted through for the class names and pulled what I could. Link is fully functional now.

```
.feature-mask
.prod-content
.pic
#pic-one, #pic-two, #pic-three, #pic-four
```